# rails ActiveRecord using relations in where method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tried to look for this in the docs, but couldn't find an answer. If I have a model Token that belongs_to a User, I can do:

```
Token.where(:user_id => u.id)
```

where u is an instance of User class.

But it's not possible to do:

```
Token.where(:user => u)
```

Shouldn't this be possible or am I missing something? (IMO much more expressive and simpler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use database column names in where clause. "user_id" is a column name, but "user" is a name of the association.

If you have association between User model and Token model, then you can do this.

```
u.tokens
```

Association should look like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tokens
 end

class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Yes, I have associate between User model and Token mode.